# How to pass a method to a directive and invoke it to pass data to a nested directive?

Tags: angularjs, methods, angularjs-directive, parameter-passing, directive

I wrote a directive, `list`, that displays a list of items.

Then I wanted to reuse this component in another directive, `wrapped-list` that would modify the list (add some items, change some values), and add some cosmetic stuff around it.

The `list` expects a list of items as parameter, then, `wrapped-list` expects the same list, plus the method that will change the list values and content.

The issue occurs when I try to invoke the method from `wrapped-list` in order to pass the data to `list`.

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n48n3qyd/10/).

I tried many crazy combinations, and could not make it work.

- `items="listFactory({items:items})"`
- `items="listFactory(items)"`
- `items="{{listFactory(items)}}"`
- `...`

No luck so far.
Any idea?

**Note**: I could make it work with `items="$parent.listBuilder(items)"`, but I don't want to depend on the parent's scope. 
Also, I know this will generate the `$digest() iteration reached error`, which is not part of this question!

Comment: You need to check your camelCase, you have listFactory in your scope and listFactory in your html. Your html should be list-factory. I just ran that in your fiddle and it worked.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a5zsm4v5/ Here is the fiddle

Comment: Wow! Thanks! A LOT!!!  :)

Comment: No problem, just remember if you define a variable in camelCase then the html version of the camelCase needs to read camel-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ohjay44](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3434773/ohjay44) commented it, the error is that `listFactory` should be referenced as `list-factory` in the HTML side.